# How to sync NSUserDefaults data with iCloud

Tags: icloud

Hi I have developed an iPhone app in which I am storing the NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults. But now I want to sync the same NSMutableArray/NSUserDefaults to iCloud and also I want to retrieve from the iCloud.
Does anybody know how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a very good discussion of this topic here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810157/can-i-use-icloud-to-sync-the-nsuserdefaults-plist-file

Answer (score 11):

I needed something similar for my app. I wrote a library that saves to both iCloud and `NSUserDefaults` and put it on GitHub. It's called [SDCloudUserDefaults](https://github.com/sdarlington/SDCloudUserDefaults).

Answer (score 9):

Use [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore). See Apple's document, [Storing Preferences in iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html)