# How do I sync my NSUserDefaults .plist to iCloud?

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, icloud

I need to sync my program's `.plist` to iCloud, both to update a `tableView` and to store in the cloud. How do I go about doing this? All the tutorials I have been looking at seem either outdated or confusing. Is there any simple way of going about this?

Comment: What is confusing? What code did you try?

Comment: tried the MKiCloudSync, but that seemed to be outdated. I really don't know where to start besides enabling iCloud under the capabilities part of the program.

Comment: *"...the core data of my program's .plist..."* is not a phrase that makes sense in the context of iOS development. Are you trying to sync a plist, or Core Data, or both, or something else maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use iCloud to sync the NSUserDefaults plist file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810157/can-i-use-icloud-to-sync-the-nsuserdefaults-plist-file)

Comment: I'm trying to sync my nsuserdefaults plush. Caleb that one seems to be outdated

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple iCloud Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html),

> iCloud supports three kinds of storage. To pick the right one (or
>   combination) for your app, make sure you understand the intent and
>   capabilities of each. The three kinds of iCloud storage are:

- **Key-value storage** for discrete values, such as preferences, settings, and simple app state.
- **Document storage** for user-visible file-based information such as word processing documents, drawings, and complex app state.
- **Core Data storage** for shoebox-style apps and server-based, multi-device database solutions for structured content. iCloud Core Data storage is built on document storage and employs the same iCloud APIs.

Therefore, you don't sync NSUserDefaults (plist) to iCloud; you would start using the [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/Reference/Reference.html) object instead.

From [Designing for Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW1):

> As you do with an NSUserDefaults object, use the iCloud key-value
>   store to save and retrieve scalar values (such as BOOL) and
>   property-list object types: NSNumber, NSString, NSDate, NSData,
>   NSArray, and NSDictionary. Array and dictionary values can hold any of
>   these value types.
>
> The NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class provides methods for reading and
>   writing each of these types, as described in NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore
>   Class Reference.

Comment: Hey @Black Frog, is it possible to store a .plist file as a Document in iCloud though? key-value storage has its limitations and Apple already provides a Plist Decoder that could be used. Apple's own documentation does say that iCloud Document storage is intended for complex app states, which is what I need a solution for.