# Save user defaults to iCloud

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

I don't have any important data in my app. But when i read this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html) i have a few questions ?

> Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot
>   otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the
>   /Documents directory and will be automatically
>   backed up by iCloud.

Do i need to save `UserDefaults` to `iCloud` ? And will my app approve if i don't use `iCloud` ?

And if i need can you show me how to save user default settings ? Because i found only tutorials how to save data from database.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810157/can-i-use-icloud-to-sync-the-nsuserdefaults-plist-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what that is saying.

When a user backup's up their devices using iTunes or iCloud, only certain parts of the app's sandbox is backed up. So there are two important aspects here:

1. Only backup data that can't be replaced.
2. Be sure to backup irreplaceable data.

`NSUserDefaults` is one of the things that will be backed up for you. You don't need to do anything special.

You don't need iCloud support unless your app has a specific need to use it.